# Ayuda con error 404 en php7 xampp

Tags: php

Lo que pasa es que tengo los archivos `PHP` en la misma carpeta y para redireccionar utilice:

```
 <a href ='store/tienda.php'> </a>
```

Pero al presionar me sale *objeto no localizado error 404* y no se porque me sale :(
Me podrían ayudar con alguna forma para redireccionar y que si funcione

Comment: Hola @Benja podrías proveer más información acerca de tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Si están en la misma carpeta entonces no debería llevar el /store

Answer (score 2):

Lo que esta pasando es que esta pidiendo llamar al archivo en la ruta: **store/tienda.php** la cual considera como un subdirectorio del que se encuentra el archivo actual, entonces lo que debes hacer son dos cosas:

**Opcion 1**

Creas una subcarpeta llamada **store** donde colocaras el archivo tienda.php y cualquiera que llames con esa ruta.

**Opcion 2**

Borrar el subdirectorio store que tienes en el link **href ='store/tienda.php'** dejando solamente el nombre del archivo tienda.php (el cual debera estar en el mismo nivel de acceso o ruta del archivo que lo esta llamando)

**Otra cosa:**
Para usar un boton

Usa la etiqueta para tener boton un dentro de la la cual se encargara de direcionarte a la ruta, te adjunto el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
    <!-- enlace sin boton -->
    <a href ='tienda.php' > ruta de tienda</a>

    <!-- Enlace con boton -->
    <a href ='tienda.php'><button>Tienda</button></a>
```

Comment: Me funcionó quitando el nombre de la carpeta :) muchas gracias y como podría redireccionar con un botón

Comment: Listo, voy a seguir tu consejo y unificar a una sola Respuesta. gracias por la correción